# Where are iFilters stored in Windows?

Tags: windows-vista, windows-search, file-filter

Windows uses iFilters for extended file search capabilities. How can I verify that a certain iFilter is installed on the computer? Is there some centralized storage location where these filters are stored? What should I be looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see a list of all installed iFilters with locations using [**IFilter Explorer**](http://www.citeknet.com/Products/IFilters/IFilterExplorer/tabid/62/Default.aspx):

[image: 1]

Answer (score 2):

The actual DLL can be anywhere on the machine since it's a COM registered DLL. Have a look at this Microsoft page for tracking down the location via the registry:

[Microsoft: Finding the Filter DLL for a File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms692488%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)